# change popover viewcontroller cornerRadius in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i am trying change cornerRadius of popUPViewController but not change 
how to change that? at the same time i have another doubt also is it possible to change cornerRadius??

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: popoverViewController.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0

Comment: You can use : https://github.com/orderella/PopupDialog

Comment: @kiri haran - where you called this

Comment: in subClass of ViewController

Comment: _uicutoutshadow view is set defalut corner radius that view may be is issue

Comment: You set it to zero?

Comment: that is not possible

Comment: Please use subclass UIPopoverBackgroundView

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems too broad to help with a specific answer. I'm trying to help assuming what your needs are:

If you're referring to the [new iOS 13 presentation style](https://miro.medium.com/max/866/1*JuPvxhMr1isAtYYXG-EDYQ.png) as "popUPViewController", you CANNOT change the corner radius of it

But, you can write your own custom transition adding your touches to it. [This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/322-custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started) is a nice place to get started with.

And yes, you can easily change the corner radius of a view:

```
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 10 //Whatever radius you'd want
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true //This line is important. Doing this will restrain yourView's layer and sublayers to the cornered mask
```

You can additionally also specify corners to apply the radius with:

```
yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner] //This will round the top-left and top-right corners
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing popupViewController.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0